# Spring MVC Authority loaded externally

Tags: java, spring, security, permissions, authority

I'm using spring mvc 4 and I have some rest services. 
Some of these methods are annotated with:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('myAuth1', 'myAuth2', 'myAuth3')")
```

So do you know if is there a way to load my permissions ('myAuth1', 'myAuth2', 'myAuth3') from an external method (maybe it load that from DB)?

Something like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority(getExtAuthForService('myService'))")
```

Thanks all
Have a good day

Fabrizio

Comment: Rather than putting annotations on your methods, you can configure the permissions in a java Security Config, at the URL level, and in the Security Config you can retrieve the permissions from a DB.

Comment: But I have to configure the permissions for all methods of all controllers.. it's not really "beautiful"

Comment: you could divide the methods in your controllers based on their acccess. Then, if /controller1/method1 and /controller1/method2 require the same access, in the SecurityConfig you'll set the access on /controller1/*. In the end, you'll have N configs, where N is the number of controllers. If that's not possible, then you can just check the permissions inside the method and call a service for the rights it requires.